# How to link data table and bar charts in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dt, rpivottable

I'm trying to make a dashboard where my data have around 7-8 columns and 1500-2000 entries. There are two columns which are numeric on which I want to do summation. Rest of the columns I want to use for slicing the data(creating subset by adding filters or slicing it according to entries of other columns).

I wanted to make dashboard where anyone can create bar charts or summary tables on the go. I was able to achieve this using `rpivottable`.

[image: Charts using rpivottable]
My second step is to show data that is being mapped in those charts. This won't make much sense if chart is at a basic level i.e *1.5k-2k entries* but as i slice the data further and further based on filters from rest of the columns. I'll come to a point where only 80 or 100 rows are satisfying a list of filters. I want to show these rows in the shiny dashboard itself.

I'm using this code to create below dashboard but the data is all the data that I have read.

```
 library(shiny)
 library(DT)
 library(rpivotTable)

  data <-read.csv("Book1.csv")

 ui =  fluidPage(
rpivotTableOutput("test"),DT::dataTableOutput('table'))

server = function(input, output) {
  output$test <- renderRpivotTable({
  rpivotTable(data = data)          })

  output$table <- renderDataTable(
    data, options = list(
      pageLength = 100

    )
  )
```

[image: Charts and Data table]

I'm able to create the charts and table using `rpivottable` and `DT` package but is there a way to link both of these ? Since Data table now is simply showing all the data that was read originally.

As in, If I want to see data that constitutes the orange bar in second picture and i click on the orange bar is there a way for the table to show data that make up the orange bar?